# Block Propagation

Tags: stake-pool, proof-of-stake

I was checking GLiveView Stats on my pool and I noticed that **served**, under **block propagation** in block producer and relays have different values, 20 on BP and 2000 on Relay after 15H of Uptime.

Why does this happen? Is it because block not passed don't need more validation?
Does anyone have some reference where I can learn from?

Thanks for your time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Guild Operator's gLiveView section](https://cardano-community.github.io/guild-operators/Scripts/gliveview/), **served** is:

> served blocks counts how many blocks were fetched by "in" peers. If this does not increase for a long time, it means the "in" peers are learning about new blocks from somewhere else (and therefore this node is not contributing towards accelerating the propagation). Overall, these metrics are helpful in tweaking the topology and/or performance of the network links.

In other words, **served** is a measure of how many blocks have been fetched by other nodes from your node. It makes sense that served will be lower for your BP because the BP is supposed to only communicate with your relays, whereas your relays are responsible for communicating with the rest of the network.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction